# Python and Selenium: I pull the hospital name from Germany. And für become when I save them into CSV file

Tags: python, csv, selenium

The website link is here:
http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/klinik-fur-anaesthesiologie-und-intensivmedizin/info/4181

As you can see on the top, the hospital name is Klinik **für** Anaesthesiologie und Intensivmedizin

This is in German.

But after I pull them down and save as CSV file.
The name changed to Klinik **f\xfcr** Anaesthesiologie und Intensivmedizin

That is so weird. I have no idea where to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Its the type of encoding, while you save the csv file, that's causing this.

You need 'utf-8' encoding. Pseudo code below:

```
with open('your_csv_file','w') as fout:
writer=csv.writer(fout)  

#encode the data 
data.encode('utf-8') 

writer.writerow(data)
```